# Adding flow variable to Mule payload

Tags: mule

What am I doing wrong here? I want to set the payload of a Mule message to a map containing multiple values:

```
<set-payload value="#[['STATUS':'OKAY','NEXT':'Test','TEXT':flowVars['myVariable']]]"/>
```

The output of this is:

```
{STATUS=OKAY, NEXT=Test, TEXT=foo}
```

I was expecting:

```
{STATUS:OKAY, NEXT:Test, TEXT:foo}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Your actual and expected results are exactly the same?

Comment: no, I want `:` instead of `=`

Comment: You can use a java code or a groovy to covert the output.Use replace function and change it as per the expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. The reason it uses "=" is just the way Mule logs the Map. The payload is still a Map. If you want ":" you can transform it to Json using `<object-to-json-transformer />` but that will output it like so:

```
{"STATUS":"OKAY", "NEXT":"Test", "TEXT":"foo"}
```